# Android Ring / Oval Shape appearing as Square?

Tags: android, android-layout, shapes

I have a list view item in android which is appearing correctly in android studio but appearing as square in the actual build when I move it to phone 
Can anyone solve this out for me please ?

### Layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout 
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/item_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            android:text="Title Name"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/item_price"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/item_title"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="10dp"
            android:text="Price : 100.00 pkr"/>


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/item_quantity"
            android:layout_width="26dp"
            android:layout_height="26dp"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginEnd="11dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="11dp"
            android:background="@drawable/rectangle"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="10"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

### Rectangle

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="#5490CC"></solid>
    <size android:width="26dp" android:height="26dp"/>
</shape>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bSqTH.jpg)

Comment: you are drawing a rectangle shape, it shows as a rectangle, but you expect it to be oval, did I miss something?

Answer (score 0):

Use a corner radius in your rectangle drawable to make it round:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
  android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="#5490CC"></solid>
    <size android:width="26dp" android:height="26dp"/>
    <corners android:radius="13dp"/>
</shape>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using  `android:shape="rectangle"` in your **rectangle.xml**. Use it as `android:shape="oval"` (if you want oval)  as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
  android:shape="oval">
    <solid android:color="#5490CC"></solid>
    <size android:width="26dp" android:height="26dp"/>
    <corners android:radius="13dp"/>
</shape>
```

I hope its work for you

Answer (score 0):

I Hope this will work for You

```
  <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:shape="oval">

      <solid android:color="#5490CC" />

      <size
        android:width="60dp"
        android:height="60dp" />

  </shape>
```